# Curve fitting histogram with Binomial distribution

Tags: python, histogram, curve-fitting, binomial-theorem

I have a histogram which represents the degree distribution of a network for me. I need to fit it to Binomial distribution, but since there is no .fit method for discrete distributions in Scipy, I don't know how to get the parameters needed for the binomial function.

It seems that I am not getting the correct parameters from the histogram since the binomial plot doesn't match the shape of the histogram.
what am I doing wrong?

```
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(5,5)# My Graph

d=np.array(list(dict(nx.degree(G,weight='weight')).values()))#Calculating 
degree distribution
c = np.array(range(0,len(d),1))# The number of nodes

h = plt.hist(d,density= True ,bins=25, stacked = True)#histogram

bionom_func= st.binom.pmf(k,n,p)# defining the binomial function


popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f=bionom_func, xdata=c, ydata=d)

estimated_n = popt[0]
estimated_p = popt[1]
modeled_y = st.binom.pmf(c, estimated_n, estimated_p)
plt.plot(c, modeled_y, 'r-')# plotting the fit curve


plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question for SO sister site stats!

Comment: Standard approach to find parameters of binomial distribution is to apply maximum likelihood method.  But your code definitely does something redundant: e.g. you define `binom_func` that is the same as `st.binom.pmf`. Why didn't you use `st.binom.pmf` instead?

Comment: @bubble you're right. I changed it a bit.